# DefaultValue for <preference /> isn't stored, does the PreferenceManager ignore it?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, android-support-library

Maybe the question is very trivial and my google-skills are not good enough but I couldn't find any solution for the following Problem.

I've built a PreferenceFragment which is compatible with the android-support-library by using [this workaround](http://blog.fordemobile.com/2012/11/display-preference-fragment-compatible.html). It works fine and was very simple to implement.

When opening this Fragment (in the `onCreate()`) the current value of each Preference will be shown in the summary of the preference object by using:

```
preference.setSummary(stringValue);
```

It works well for all `EditTextPreference`, `ListPreference` and - with a simple addition - for `CheckboxPreference`, too. But I have another Preference:

```
<Preference 
    android:key="minInputLength"
    android:defaultValue="@integer/numberPickerInputLengthDefaultValue"
    android:title="@string/minInputLength"/>
```

When the cache of the App is empty and the `onCreate` method is called, the summary of this and only this preference is empty, although I've called this method:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.layout.fragment_settings, true);
```

in the Main activity. Otherwise the summaries of all the other Preferences would be empty too.

The Preference above just opens a Dialog, which contains a simple NumberPicker in its content area. If I change the value within the NumberPicker and exit the dialog by pressing the PositiveButton of the dialog, the summary of this Preference changes like expected. If I **clear the cache** and open the fragment again **the summary is empty again**.

So I tried to figure out why and displayed all SharedPreferences via LogCat and recognized that this and only this preference is missing. **This is the reason why I ask myself: does the PreferenceManager ignore the defaultValue, which is declared in the xml, of `<preference />`?**

EDIT:
Or is this problem caused by the workaround I mentioned?

These two Links summarize my research, but there was no solution for my Problem (or I am just too blind to see):

- [defaultValue from xml preference file isn't stored - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171155/defaultvalue-from-xml-preference-file-isnt-stored-why)
- [Android Preferences: How to load the default values when the user hasn't used the preferences-screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691772/android-preferences-how-to-load-the-default-values-when-the-user-hasnt-used-th)